# Multiple find in brackets excel function

Tags: excel

I have a string that I am trying to convert and seperate:

**time (123) (203)**

however some strings have

**time (123) (203) (547)**

I am trying to get the value inside the brackets which I can get with:

`(MID(A1, FIND("(",A1')+1, FIND(")",A1') − FIND("(",title_edit 'A1) − 1))`

this returns **123**. Which is great. I just need to get all the numbers so that any inside bracket, to equal 123 203 547. Is there a function that I am missing, or an easy way to create this?

Comment: Do you want them in one cell or one per cell?

Comment: One cell,  basically get whats inside any bracket and return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TEXTJOIN() as an array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(",REPT(" ",999)),999*ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(","")))),999)),FIND(")",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(",REPT(" ",999)),999*ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(","")))),999))&")")-1))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

---

TEXTJOIN() is only available with a subscription to Office 365 Excel.

If you do not have that then add this code to a module attached to the workbook and use the formula as described above.

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

---

The TEXTJOIN method will only return those that are between `()`.  If your constant, `time` in your examples, is always in the front you can use this simpler formula:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)-1,LEN(A1)),"(",""),")",""))
```

This will exclude anything before the first `(` from the output:

[image]

But on something like this: `(123) time (203) (547)` it will return `123 time 203 547` where the TEXTJOIN will return `123 203 547`

Comment: You sir, are a wizard and a scholar. Thank you very much.

Comment: if I then wrapped this with a substitute tag I guess it would do the opposite and remove it surely.. I will investigate further and hopefully help someone with that piece of info.

Comment: Wrapped what?  I have a few options in my answer.

Comment: I just meant if someone ever wanted to delete rather than append.

Comment: for reference I used the the trim function as i am using something similar to openoffice

Answer (score 1):

Try Replace `(` with nothing and `)` with nothing (separately) then apply Text to Columns with space as the delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

```
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B7, "(", ""),")"," ")
```

Comment: This does not work, as it equals time 123 203 547 it has to get the "(" as its parameter thats why I am struggling without a regular expression

Comment: Then add another SUBSTITUTE to remove `time` @m33bo

Comment: it has to get any character inside brackets and ignore the rest thats why my previous formula was closer as it got the bracket and returned the content

Answer (score 0):

=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(CLEAN(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1)))),"(",""),")","")

Would provide similar results as to Scott's answer which I just saw was accepted.

It will rely on using text to columns on the formula results as other answers have suggested